# How to resolve this error while installing pyrebase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, pip, pyrebase

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rkapr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9iaimw1v\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users
\\rkapr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9iaimw1v\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code,
 __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rkapr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0trba1yq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\python38\Include\pycrypt
odome'
         cwd: C:\Users\rkapr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-9iaimw1v\pycryptodome\
```

Complete output (364 lines):

```
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\Cipher
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS\SigGenPSS_186-2.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS\SigGenPSS_186-3.txt -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS\SigVerPSS_186-3.rsp -> build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_vectors\PKCS1-PSS
    Skipping optional fixer: buffer
    Skipping optional fixer: idioms
    Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
    Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
    running build_ext
    ----------------------------------------


ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\rkapr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9iaimw1v\\pycryptodome\\setup
.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\rkapr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-9iaimw1v\\pycryptodome\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"
'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\rkapr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-0trba1yq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-hea
ders 'c:\python38\Include\pycryptodome' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 2):

Install pyrebase4 instead. It is a newer well maintained pyrebase library.

```
pip install pyrebase4
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Pip then install again

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

pip install pyrebase.
```

Solved my Problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `pycryptodome` separately using this command.
Make sure to run the terminal as administrator.

```
pip install pycryptodome
```